# Querying chaincode is only successful in ~3/5 cases with nodejs

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I successfully installed and instantiated chaincode on my chain. I'm able to enroll the admin and register a user trough nodejs. If I query the chaincode it only returns a correct response around 3 out of 5 times. The rest throws errors that the chaincode can't be found.

The chaincode installed is the basic example from the fabric samples.
My js file to query the chaincode (based on the fabcar example):

```
/*
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

'use strict';

const { FileSystemWallet, Gateway } = require('fabric-network');
const path = require('path');

const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'connection-org1.json');

async function main() {
try {

    // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
    const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
    const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
    console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

    // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
    const userExists = await wallet.exists('user1');
    if (!userExists) {
        console.log('An identity for the user "user1" does not exist in the wallet');
        console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
        return;
    }

    // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
    const gateway = new Gateway();
    await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });

    // Get the network (channel) our contract is deployed to.
    const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');

    // Get the contract from the network.
    const contract = network.getContract('mycc');

    const result = await contract.evaluateTransaction('query', 'a');
    console.log(`Transaction has been evaluated, result is: ${result}`);

} catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to evaluate transaction: ${error}`);
    process.exit(1);
}
}

main();
```

The successful queries with the errors, nothing has been changed between those executions and they have been called with around 5 seconds beetween them.

```
root@devserver ~/fabric-samples/bla/first-network # node index.js 
Transaction has been evaluated, resultb is: 210

root@devserver ~/fabric-samples/bla/first-network # node index.js 
Transaction has been evaluated, resultb is: 210

root@devserver ~/fabric-samples/bla/first-network # node index.js 
Transaction has been evaluated, resultb is: 210

root@devserver ~/fabric-samples/bla/first-network # node index.js 
Transaction has been evaluated, resultb is: 210

root@devserver ~/fabric-samples/bla/first-network # node index.js 
2019-09-09T18:53:24.646Z - warn: [Query]: evaluate: Query ID "[object Object]" of peer "peer1.PharmaProducer.bigpharma.com:8051" failed: message=cannot retrieve package for chaincode mycc/1.0, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/mycc.1.0: no such file or directory, stack=Error: cannot retrieve package for chaincode mycc/1.0, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/mycc.1.0: no such file or directory
  at self._endorserClient.processProposal (/root/fabric-samples/bla/first-network/node_modules/fabric-network/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:140:36)
  at Object.onReceiveStatus (/root/fabric-samples/bla/first-network/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1207:9)
  at InterceptingListener._callNext (/root/fabric-samples/bla/first-network/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
  at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/root/fabric-samples/bla/first-network/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
  at callback (/root/fabric-samples/bla/first-network/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24), status=500, , url=grpcs://localhost:8051, name=peer1.PharmaProducer.bigpharma.com:8051, grpc.max_receive_message_length=-1, grpc.max_send_message_length=-1, grpc.keepalive_time_ms=120000, grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms=120000, grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms=20000, grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data=0, grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls=1, name=peer1.PharmaProducer.bigpharma.com:8051, grpc.ssl_target_name_override=peer1.PharmaProducer.bigpharma.com, grpc.default_authority=peer1.PharmaProducer.bigpharma.com, isProposalResponse=true
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: cannot retrieve package for chaincode mycc/1.0, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/mycc.1.0: no such file or directory
```

I expect the code to successfuly return a correct result every time and not randomly show an error that the code doesn't exist.

Any insight on how this can happen is appreciated.

Comment: how many peers do you have in your org ? I'm guessing you have more than 1 but only installed the chaincode package onto 1 of them ?

Comment: @david_k I have 2 peers per org and installed it on peer0 of every org. So yes your guess is correct.

Comment: What version of the node-sdk are you using ? because unless peer0 is not responding the evaluate should detect that peer1 can't return a result and try peer0. You can get a node-sdk by setting an env var `export HFC_LOGGING='{"debug":"console"}'`. It's also curious as to why it looks like it tries peer1 first when the other times it is trying peer0 first. But a log would provide more detail.

Comment: I doubt this would make a difference but add `await gateway.disconnect()` at the end of your code. I tried this and didn't face any issues. Could you do `docker logs <PEER_NAME` and `docker logs <CC_CONTAINER>` to see if any errors were thrown there. If you installed on only 1 peer and not the other, its possible a random peer is chosen from the connection profile for the query so statistically 50% of the time you should get an error. The docker logs of each peer would give more info.

Comment: @david_k I can't find the node-sdk version but here are the logs first output is from a working example and the second is from a non working example:

https://pastebin.com/itZXCmuJ

Comment: @VarunAgarwal I added the disconnect and checked the logs during chaincode execution, no errors are thrown by the peers but it somehow switches to peer1 on execution:

https://pastebin.com/PkGt8TTS

i'll check the logs during chaincode installation but since peer0 responds fine on the same org and then tries to jump to peer1 and fails I doubt that this is the issue

Comment: Well in the query transaction, I believe it will pick one random peer from the client section of the connection profile that is within the channel, so if you don;t have the chaincode installed on both peers that could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: The way to find the version you are using is to go to the node_modules/fabric-network directory and look at the package.json file it will have a version field with the actual version installed.

Comment: @david_k The version says 1.4.4

https://pastebin.com/PgaUSRMA

Comment: @david_k Is it possible to choose peer nodes which we are going to query when invoking `contract.evaluateTransaction()`? These queries are not dependent on other endorsing peers, so it makes sense. At least it seems that way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the logs I can see why sometimes you get peer0 and occasionally you get peer1, and that is because the discovery results and processing result in it not being possible to get the list of peers in any particular order so with 2 peers in your org and the fact that this is not a long running app but a short running invocation sometimes peer0 will be first in the list of peers and sometimes peer1. Because you have only installed the chaincode on peer0, peer1 can't honour the evaluate request and return an error.

The node-sdk should detect this and then try peer0 but either you are using an older version of the node-sdk which definitely had an issue where it did not try a different peer or the node-sdk is thinking this is (incorrectly, but may not be able to distinguish) a chaincode response and passes that back to the caller. 
The solution to avoid the error is to install the chaincode on all the peers.

Comment: Installing it on every peer fixed the issue, I would prefer if there would be an automatic check whether the chaincode is installed and query the next peer if not but this is an easy fix. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @user3399276 How did you install it on all peers? If I plain install the chaincode with `docker exec -it cli peer chaincode install ...` the chaincode cannot be instantiated because the consortium is not met.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer! I have verified it by installing chaincode on all my peers. Then the problem no longer appears. Thank you