# Error while executing the transaction dynamically in hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I have modified the fabcar example to execute in a particular time interval. It works fine upto 4th or 5th times. Then it start showing error like this.

```
2020-02-24T10:33:09.018Z - warn: [Query]: evaluate: Query ID "[object Object]" of peer "peer1.org1.example.com:8051" failed: message=cannot retrieve package for chaincode fabcar/1.0, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/fabcar.1.0: no such file or directory, stack=Error: cannot retrieve package for chaincode fabcar/1.0, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/fabcar.1.0: no such file or directory
    at self._endorserClient.processProposal (/home/djaxtech/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:140:36)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/djaxtech/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1207:9)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/djaxtech/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/djaxtech/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
    at callback (/home/djaxtech/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24), status=500, , url=grpcs://localhost:8051, name=peer1.org1.example.com:8051, grpc.max_receive_message_length=-1, grpc.max_send_message_length=-1, grpc.keepalive_time_ms=120000, grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms=120000, grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms=20000, grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data=0, grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls=1, name=peer1.org1.example.com:8051, grpc.ssl_target_name_override=peer1.org1.example.com, grpc.default_authority=peer1.org1.example.com, isProposalResponse=true
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: cannot retrieve package for chaincode fabcar/1.0, error open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/fabcar.1.0: no such file or directory
```

Tried the answer from this link [Querying chaincode is only successful in ~3/5 cases with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859872/querying-chaincode-is-only-successful-in-3-5-cases-with-nodejs). But I could not able to install the chaincode in peer1 through CLI container. Facing error like this.

```
Error: error getting endorser client for install: endorser client failed to connect to peer1.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 172.23.0.11:7051: connect: connection refused"
```

How to resolve?

Comment: I have the same error on my fabcar example too. The bkc answers correctly to the nodeJs 3 times out of 4.

Answer (score 0):

It has been cleared by installing chaincode in both the peers. Here I am giving code snippet to install the chaincode via ./startFabric.sh

**Installation in peer1 0f Organisation 1**

```
echo "Installing smart contract on peer1.org1.example.com"
docker exec \
  -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP \
  -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:8051 \
  -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${ORG1_MSPCONFIGPATH} \
  -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${ORG1_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
  cli \
  peer chaincode install \
    -n fabcar \
    -v 1.0 \
    -p "$CC_SRC_PATH" \
    -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE"
```

**Installation in peer1 of organisation 2**

```
echo "Installing smart contract on peer1.org2.example.com"
docker exec \
  -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP \
  -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:10051 \
  -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${ORG2_MSPCONFIGPATH} \
  -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${ORG2_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
  cli \
  peer chaincode install \
    -n fabcar \
    -v 1.0 \
    -p "$CC_SRC_PATH" \
    -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE"
```

**In Invoke initLedger()**

```
docker exec \
  -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP \
  -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${ORG1_MSPCONFIGPATH} \
  cli \
  peer chaincode invoke \
    -o orderer.example.com:7050 \
    -C mychannel \
    -n fabcar \
    -c '{"function":"initLedger","Args":[]}' \
    --waitForEvent \
    --tls \
    --cafile ${ORDERER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
    --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 \
    --peerAddresses peer1.org1.example.com:8051 \
    --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051 \
    --peerAddresses peer1.org2.example.com:10051 \
    --tlsRootCertFiles ${ORG1_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
    --tlsRootCertFiles ${ORG1_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
    --tlsRootCertFiles ${ORG2_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
    --tlsRootCertFiles ${ORG2_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE}
```

Then start the ./startFabric.sh. It will work!